# Dynamic wheres using TypeORM

Tags: typeorm

I need to generate a query that looks something like:

```
SELECT v.* FROM versions v
WHERE 
  (v.id1 = 1 AND v.id2 = 1) OR 
  (v.id1 = 3 AND v.id2 = 2) OR
  (v.id1 = 5 AND v.id2 = 6) OR ...
```

The parameter to my function contains a list of these paired ids. Unfortunately, `id1` and `id2` are not the primary keys of this table so I can't use `.whereIdsIn()`.

I am aware of the `Brackets` object but can't for the life of me figure out how to create a dynamic number of them.

Comment: Could you put your entity classes for the reference. It will be easier for the person who answers to your question and also for you to quickly use it and test it

Answer (score 2):

Since you put a generic query, I'll try to answer this generally. You can do something like this:

```js
async foo(tupleList: [number, number][]) {
  const builder = createQueryBuilder(Version, 'v');
  for (const tuple of tupleList) {
    builder.orWhere(new Brackets(qb => {
      qb.where("v.id1 = :id1", { id1: tuple[0] })
        .andWhere("v.id2 = :id2", { id2: tuple[1] })
    }));
  }
  const result = await builder.getMany();
}
```